# Typescript Why type guard does not work as expected for array of objects of type null-able union(strictNullChecks enabled)

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

```
type Field = {test: {more: number} | null}
let fields: Field[] = [{test: {more: 55}}]
```

Transpiler throws error regardless of the type guard:

```
if (fields[0].test) {
  fields[0].test.more = 55 // object is possibly null
}
```

Here no error:

```
function f(field: Field) {
  if (field.test) field.test.more = 15 // no error
}
```

Comment: I don't think flow analysis keeps track of array index types... it only does so for fields and local variables..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir This should be an answer, it is the correct one.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha wanted to find a reference for this and didn't have the time, thought someone else would get to it. I added the answer now with a reference to the ticket :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type flow does not keep track of array index access, so it will not remember that you checked the `0` index for `null`. This was [considered](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11483) but apparently not implemented due to performance considerations You can put the value in a local variable and type guards will work as expected on those:

```
type Field = {test: {more: number} | null}
let fields: Field[] = [{test: {more: 55}}]
let d = fields[0];
if (d.test) {
    d.test.more = 55 // object is possibly null
}
```

Comment: wins with https://stackoverflow.com/a/49879261/8191072 because of mentioning possibility of doing `let d = fields[0];`

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems that TypeScript doesn't keep track of nulls in Array indexes, which is a bit strange ... maybe an issue could be opened at GitHub about it. Anyway, there is a way to prevent that error. Once you make that check, you know that `test` is not `null`, so you can do:

```
if (fields[0].test !== null) {
  fields[0].test!.more = 55 // object is possibly null
}
```

The `!` after `test` will tell the compiler that that variable is defined and different from `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: There was a ticket, they are not doing it : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11483